# Heap corruption detected

Tags: c++

I have a very simple code like below

```
#include <iostream>
struct mystruct
{
    char *m1;   
};

void pass(char **, const char *);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char *p = NULL;
    pass (&p, "hello"); 

    struct mystruct *mP = NULL;
    mP = new mystruct;

    pass ( &mP->m1, "hi");
    //std::cout << mP->m1;

    return 0;
}

void pass (char **p1, const char *q1)
{
    *p1 = new char (3);
    *p1[2] = '\0';
    strcpy (*p1,q1);
    std::cout << strlen (*p1);
    std::cout << *p1;
    delete []*p1;
}
```

and get the error `heap corruption detected!` when `delete[]` is reached ...Please help !!!

Comment: What platform ? Smells like Windows...

Comment: @Paul: I didn't realize Windows was that smelly :)

Comment: @Armen: Windows code has a unique smell. :)

Comment: Any particular reason you're using pointers-to-pointers rather than references? And ugly self-allocated `char` buffers rather than `std::string`?

Answer (score 8):

`*p1 = new char (3);`

allocates 1 char and initializes it with value 3.

You meant

```
*p1 = new char [3]; //square brackets
```

**Update:**

The other error is this line

```
*p1[2] = '\0';
```

Although this line is completely unnecessary (strcpy will take care of what concerns you) this is wrong bacause of precedence of [] and *. You meant

```
(*p1)[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply...but I meant [3] with square brackets...Its still the same error

Comment: @Sam: please only ever copy and paste actual code when asking questions on SO - it makes no sense to re-type code and it nearly always introduces errors, which just wastes everyone's time, including yours.

Comment: Thanks *p1[2] = '\0' was a problem; It has worked !....
@Paul - did not understand you....i copied the actual code...

Answer (score 4):

In `pass` you are trying to allocate 3 characters for `p1`, but then you are copying a string to it with `strcpy` thats longer than that.  You need to pass the length of `q1` into `pass` and allocate accordingly.

Also, you need to do `*p1 = new char[SIZE];`

Where `SIZE` is a value big enough to store the string in `q1`.

Comment: Thanks ...tried now below code void pass (char **p1, const char *q1)
{
    *p1 = new char [strlen (q1)+1];
 *p1[strlen (q1)] = '\0';
 strcpy (*p1,q1);
 std::cout << strlen (*p1);
 std::cout << *p1;
 delete []*p1;
}  still the same error ....I am new to c++....

Comment: +1 - But it isn't just the `SIZE` but `SIZE+1` ( for the termination character ). @Sam - There is no need to fill the termination character. strcpy takes care of it when you do not run out of buffer. This is not needed `*p1[strlen (q1)] = '\0';`

Comment: @Sam, as Armen said, you also need to do `(*p1)[strlen(q1)];` the brackets are needed to make sure its dereferencing before the index operation.

Comment: @Mahesh, when I said `SIZE` is big enough to store the string, I meant including the NULL byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
*p1 = new char (3);
```

calls char constructor and allocates one char. then in

```
strcpy (*p1,q1);
```

you are copying "hello" which is 6 char. this leads to allocated buffer overflow